# Can i change VSCode Terminal Icon to the original one?

Tags: visual-studio-code

the question and picture is described as following:

maybe i clicked somewhere else, i don't know what happend, the icon of the terminal choose changed, after it changed, i feel bad. is there sombody can help me change the icon to the original one?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOXqw.png

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, changed from list to icon (tab), but I managed to change it back. This is how I did:

1. Click the drop down button next to the "plus icon"
2. A drop down list with option will appear
3. Choose "Configure Terminal Settings"
4. The Settings will open in the Editor Area
5. Navigate down to the feature "Terminal > Integrated > Tabs: Focus Mode"
6. Uncheck this feature and it's done

Now, if you just want to change the icon for CMD, then you just need to:

1. Click the icon (the CMD icon you indicated on the image you sent)
2. A drop down list with options will appear
3. Choose the option "Change Icon..."
4. Near the top of your window, a drop down list will appear
5. Simply type 'terminal' and a lot of icons will be shown
6. Choose the icon you want